# How to render formset manually?

Tags: django

I can't figure out how to render formset manually. I created formset like this: `ImageFormset = modelformset_factory(PostImages, fields=('image',), extra=0, can_delete=True)`.

And when I render formset I get this:

[image]

I want to get rid of all this text and write my own, how do I do this?

Comment: [Manually rendered can_delete and can_order](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/formsets/#manually-rendered-can-delete-and-can-order) I don't think this is exactly what you're looking for but might spark some ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. All we need is to apply widget to imageField:

```
from django.forms.widgets import FileInput
ImageFormset = modelformset_factory(PostImages, fields=('image',), widgets= {'image': FileInput}, extra=0, can_delete=True)
```

And render form like this:

```
{{ formset.management_form }}
{% for f in formset %}
    {% for field in f.hidden_fields %}
        {{ field }}
    {% endfor %}
    <img src="/media/{{ f.image.value}}" style="max-width: 400px;" alt="">
    {{ f.image }}
    {{ f.DELETE }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you can add label to your ImageFormset like this :

```
ImageFormset = modelformset_factory(PostImages, fields=('image',), extra=0, can_delete=True, labels={'FieldsName': 'CustomFieldName','OtherFieldsName': 'OtherCustomFieldName'}).
```

Comment: Sorry, but that's not I actually want. I want to access the 'Choose file' button in template

Comment: I mean, to access this button like this: {{ form.field.button }}